# Replace full-width numerals with half-width numerals

Tags: regular-expressions, replace

I'd like to convert numerals from half-width to full-width characters with a simple regex search and replace as follows:

> replace-regexp-in-string *regexp rep string &optional fixedcase literal subexp start*

```
(replace-regexp-in-string '(０ １ ２ ３ ４ ５ ６ ７ ８ ９) '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
```

Evaluating the above code in a buffer gave me this error:

`(wrong-number-of-arguments (3 . 7) 2)`

I suppose the missing argument is the *string*, which I assumed would take care of itself when I evaluate the code using <kbd>M-:</kbd> on a buffer.

How do I do this correctly?

---

## Follow-up Question:

I would like to abstract the commands given in @Tobias' answer into a single function, so that I can call them with a single key-binding.

Here's my attempt:

```
(defun num-half2full
    (query-replace-regexp [0-9]
              /,(string (+ (string-to-char \&) (- ?０ ?0)))))
```

### Error:

```
(error "Malformed arglist: (query-replace-regexp [0-9] / (, (string (+ (string-to-char &) (- 65296 48)))))")
```

---

## My last attempt at writing the function:

(defun num-full2half ()
  "Convert numbers from full-width to half-width"
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (replace-regexp "[０－９]"
  (quote (replace-eval-replacement replace-quote
    (string (+ (string-to-char (match-string 0)) 48 (- 65296)))))))

The expected replacement did not take place in the buffer at which M-x<\kbd>(num-full2half) was called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `regplace-regexp-in-string` does not magically substitute the buffer string into the `STRING` argument. It is a function but not a command (does not have an interactive specification).

The command you are actually looking for is `query-replace-regexp` which can be used interactively and is bound to <kbd>C-M-%</kbd>.

Use: <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> `[0-9]` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\,(string (+ (string-to-char \&) (- ?０ ?0)))` <kbd>RET</kbd> to replace normal digit chars with wide digit chars.

The escape sequence `\,(...)` allows you to call Elisp from the replacement string. In our case the regexp is the character group `[0-9]` of normal digits. Used Elisp forms:

- ?０ and `?0` give the character codes for the wide zero char and the normal zero char (e.g., ASCII code 48 for `?0`)
- `(- ?０ ?0)` computes the offset between the wide digit zero char and the normal digit zero char
- `\&` is replaced with the match string, (e.g., `"１"`)
- `(string-to-char \&)` delivers the char code of the first char in the match string, (in our case the match string only contains one digit char)
- `(+ (string-to-char \&) (- ?０ ?0)))` adds the offset between wide digits and normal digits to the found digit char.
- `(string (+ (string-to-char \&) (- ?０ ?0))))` Generates a string containing only the wide digit char that we just have calculated.

---

The inverse is also possible:

Use: <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> `[０-９]` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\,(string (+ (string-to-char \&) (- ?0 ?０)))` <kbd>RET</kbd> to replace wide digit chars with normal digit chars. The essential differences to the `query-replace` above are:

- we search for wide digit chars instead of normal digit chars
- we have changed the sign of the offset `(- ?0 ?０)` instead of `(- ?０ ?0)`

---

The command <kbd>M-x</kbd> `list-command-history` <kbd>RET</kbd> reveals the actually called command:

```el
(query-replace-regexp "[0-9]"
  (quote (replace-eval-replacement replace-quote
    (string (+ (string-to-char (match-string 0)) 48 (- 65296))))) nil nil nil nil nil)
```

As Elisp beginner you can just use that code in your Elisp function. (Even if the doc-string of `query-replace-regexp` says that this function is for interactive use only.)

If you want to avoid the query you can remove the prefix `query-` and all the nils at the tail of the argument list:

```el
(replace-regexp "[0-9]"
  (quote (replace-eval-replacement replace-quote
    (string (+ (string-to-char (match-string 0)) 48 (- 65296))))))
```

---

Now a word about what the doc string of `query-replace-regexp` actually suggests.

It wants you to write a loop:

```el
(goto-char (point-min)) ;; maybe first go to the beginning of the accessible buffer
(while (re-search-forward "[０-９]" nil t)
  (replace-match (string (+ (string-to-char (match-string 0)) (- ?0 ?０))))
```

Comment: This replaces normal characters `0 1 2 3` etc. with full-width `０１２３` etc. ? I actually need the other way round. And because `[０-９] doesn't work in regex, we might need do specify the search elements individually: `[０１２３] etc.

Comment: How do we make sure the full and half-width digits map to each other?

Comment: @Sati See my edit. You can also replace wide digit chars with normal digit chars. The character group `[０-９]` actually works. (Tested with `GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2019-09-16` on WSL.) The characters for the numbers have consecutive codes in their natural order.

Comment: Can these processes be abstracted into a single function or command that can be call with a single key-binding?

Comment: You can use `ucs-normalize-NFKC-string` to convert the full width ０ into the half width 0.

Comment: @Sati Just do what you need interactively and call `M-x list-command-history` aferwards. There you find the corresponding lisp forms whose you can use in your Elisp code. (E.g., define a one-keystroke command.)

Comment: @xuchunyang If that works please write your own answer. That gives Sati the possibility to accept it.

Comment: @xuchunyang I would like to only convert the numerals, but not other full-width punctuation like `！？， ` so I still need to search for the numbers first.

Comment: @xuchunyang Regardless of what Sati said. Your suggestion is worth an answer. Maybe, other users do not care about other characters. It would be nice if you mentioned in that answer that other utf8 chars are also "normalized".

Comment: @Tobias Yes, that would be a nice addition to the knowledge, thank you.

Comment: By the way, Xah Lee wrote a [code](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_convert_chinese_punctuation.html) that seems to be doing exactly the same thing as the `ucs` function. Do check it out. I wasn't able to get it to work (ignoring the focus on numbers), though.

Comment: @Tobias, could you explain a bit more precisely what this `\,(string (+ (string-to-char \&) (- ?0 ?０)))` part of the original code does and how it corresponds to the resultant command code `(quote (replace-eval-replacement replace-quote
    (string (+ (string-to-char (match-string 0)) 48 (- 65296))))) nil nil nil nil nil)`? I suspect it's got something to do with macros, but it's too puzzling to wrap my head around this at present.

Comment: And `(get-char-code-property ?０ 'digit-value) ;; 0` works too.

Comment: @Sati: I think you are a bit mistaken. The input `\,(string (+ (string-to-char \&) (- ?0 ?０)))` of `replace-regexp` is the replacement **string**. At this stage it is not yet code but a string. The function `query-replace-compile-replacement` which is called in the interactive form of `replace-regexp` generates code from this string if needed. The replacement string can contain [much more stuff]. In most cases the injected lisp forms `\,(...)` are only a small part of the overall replacement string. That is actually the application where they are most useful.

Comment: `(- ?0 ?０)` seems to be asking for the (unicode?) range of characters between `0` and `０`? `\&` wants the entire string to be replaced; in this case, the entire string of the search result will be evaluated as an argument to `string-to-char`,  which returns a numeric value that is supposed to represent the first character in that matched string. What does adding the two values together mean? Why do we need to concatenate them in a `(string)`? And what's the function of the two `?`s in front of the `0０`s?

Comment: @Sati: Actually, only `\,` and `\&` are special. All the parentheses belong to ordinary [list forms](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Classifying-Lists.html#Classifying-Lists).

Comment: [Reposting this comment because of typo. It refers to my question above. ] @Tobias no I am perfectly aware that the "code" in question is actually the replacement string by reading the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html). (You can use Lisp expressions to calculate parts of the replacement string.) I just struggle to understand what all the symbols (`?` `string-to-char` etc.) mean, especially when put together in this way.

Comment: @Tobias: I just edited my earlier comment. I have no question about the meaning of the parentheses; the () in the original post were supposed to contain the symbols in question, which I have left out. My questions above should be much clearer.

Comment: @Sati I have added a detailed description what the lisp forms do. When you acknowledge that this list clears all still outstanding problems we should definitively clean up the comments I.e: Delete all comments starting with https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53698/replace-full-width-numerals-with-half-width-numerals/53699?noredirect=1#comment83816_53699.

Comment: @Tobias: One last issue: the `?` in `?0`, it's not the usual `?` in Regex. In Regex,  a `?` would mean the character before it can either be present or not; or stand for non-greedy matching in certain cases. `?0` quite obviously belongs to neither. So is `?` a special case here too?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100990/discussion-on-answer-by-tobias-replace-full-width-numerals-with-half-width-numer).